# SwitchMap in APP_INITLIZER is repeating infinitely

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a script to validate users that I want going off during app initlization, so I'm providing a `APP_INITIALIZER` in `app.module`. It makes an HTTP call, which runs through two `switchMaps` and then gets converted to a promise. The HTTP call works, and then the first switchMap fires once, and then the second switchMap fires infinitely and locks the app. I can't figure out what's going on, nor can I figure out how to debug this. It worked at some point, and I'm not sure what change broke it.

Here's the method that gets returned to the `APP_INITLIZER`:

```
validateUser() {
    let jwt = this.getJWT();
    if (jwt && jwt.length) {
        return this.api
            .get<{ data: { tokenValid: boolean } }>('/users/validateToken', { token: jwt })
            .pipe(
                switchMap(response => {
                    if (response.data.tokenValid) {
                        this.setUser()
                        return this.currentUser$.asObservable()
                    } else {
                        return ObservableOf(false);
                    }
                }),
                switchMap(currentUser => {
                    if (currentUser) {
                        currentUser.getEvents();
                        this.setCurrentUser(currentUser);
                    } else {
                        this.logout()
                    }

                    return ObservableOf(true);
                })
            )
            .toPromise();
    }

    return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

`currentUser$` is a behavior subject if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

You returns `this.currentUser$.asObservable()` in the first SwitchMap.

Then you update current user from the 2nd SwitchMap `this.setCurrentUser(currentUser)`.

This will cause observable inside the first SwitchMap emit a new value. So it goes indefinitely.

While I think your code can be improved, the simplest solution is to change one line.

`this.currentUser$.asObservable().pipe(first())`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even consider it could create a feedback loop... I thought a switchMap would be linear. Yah, I know my code could use a LOT of improvement (that's one method, you'd cry at the entire structure), just don't have anyone who can advise me, heh.